# Play Framework: play-plugins-mailer Unresolved dependency

Tags: scala, plugins, dependencies, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have problem with Play Framework and sbt-plugins-mailer.

```
$ activator --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.8-M5

playVersion: 2.3.8
sbtVersion: 0.13.5
scalaVersion: 2.11.1
```

I want to create Play Framework application which works in OpenShift cloud.
I downloaded code from:
https://github.com/JamesSullivan/play2-openshift-quickstart and created my own application on Openshift using this template.

Here is build.sbt file from template:

```
import sbt.Keys._

name := """play2demo"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2.0",
  javaWs
)

val appDependencies = Seq( 
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18" 
)
```

I want to send emails so I added this line:

```
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.3.1",
```

Since this change activator returns unresolved dependences,
when I try to compile this project on localhost:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe#play-plugins-mailer_2.11;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

My plugins.sbt file contains:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
```

I created play.plugins file:

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

But still i have compile errors.

Comment: make sure you imported it as sbt project and "use sbt shell for build and import " is disabled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.0"`     try this as dependency in your sbt file.

Comment: Thanks curious, just curious how did you figure this out. I searched for it over here https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/play/ and didn't find it.